# How to set the constraints for custom cell label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

1. i have uilabel ,it is created via programmatically width and height mentioned in tableview cell class.
2. now i like to add constraints for that uilabel.

3.i want trailing space to content view and leading space to content view ,then top and bottom space to content view.

4.i am know how to create constraints via storyboard ,but struct to done that programmatically .

this is what i tried.

```
 [cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.lblDisplay attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

please anybody help me to set the constraints what i mentioned above....

Comment: Have you worked with custom cell? Where you customize whole cell?

Comment: i am using third party tableview (i.e)TQMultistagetebleview ,for that i have created one custom tableview cell,in that cell one uilabel is available i am using that uilabel in tableview datasource method...

Comment: Use masonry to add constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) provides easier way to add constraints programmatically.

LEt's say you have a UIView and you want to add constraints to it:

```
   UIView *superview = self;

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[superview addSubview:view1];

UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[superview addConstraints:@[

    //view1 constraints
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:padding.top],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:padding.left],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:-padding.bottom],

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:superview
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:-padding.right],

 ]];
```

The same can be done using masonry with the following code:

```
UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top); //with is an optional semantic filler
    make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(-padding.bottom);
    make.right.equalTo(superview.mas_right).with.offset(-padding.right);
}];
```

Or even shorter

```
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(superview).with.insets(padding);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code nowhere talks about the height, width of the view, instead it only mentions the position. For a constraint to be valid you need Height, Width, XPosition and YPosition of the your view. You could simply follow this and your standard spacing to your label will be fine.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
NSArray *constraintsV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[contentView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

[containerView addConstraints:constraintsV];

viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
NSArray *constraintsH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[contentView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

[containerView addConstraints:constraintsH];
```

Comment: to use container view we need to assign the container position i am correct?

Comment: Yes you'll need that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.contentView addSubview:label];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-leadingSpace-[label]-trailingSpace-|" options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{@"leadingSpace": @(10),
                                                                                   @"trailingSpace": @(10)}
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-topSpace-[label]-bottomSpace-|" options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{@"topSpace": @(10),
                                                                                   @"bottomSpace": @(10)}
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
```